# Doxygen end of line comments on declarations in Python

Tags: python, doxygen

In C/C++, you can force doxygen to recognize that a comment applies to the text preceding it on a line. Any of these:

```
int my_variable;                 /*!< This is my variable */
int my_variable;                 /**< This is my variable */
int my_variable;                 //!< This is my variable
int my_variable;                 ///< This is my variable
```

adds the string to the documentation for `my_variable`. Trying the equivalent in Python doesn't seem to work. This works:

```
## This is my variable
my_variable = None
```

This:

```
my_variable = None               ## This is my variable
my_other_variable = None
```

attaches the documentation to `my_other_variable`, as you'd expect, but both of these:

```
my_variable = None               ##< This is my variable
my_variable = None               #!< This is my variable
```

seem to just discard the documentation. Is there a way to do the equivalent of `//!<` in Python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, at the moment this is not supported.

The parser for Python was provided by a couple of students. While they did a good job overall, they did not implement all the features that are available for C/C++.

Two most notable features that are missing are:

- support for documenting stuff after the definition
   
  https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=361813
- support for cross-referencing and call graphs
  http://old.nabble.com/Python-callgraph-td24224054.html

Hopefully I get around to add these in the future, but any help is welcome.