# Documentation after members in python (with doxygen)

Tags: python, doxygen

I am using doxygen and have the following code:

```
def __init__(self):
    '''

    '''
    if not '_ready' in dir(self) or not self._ready:
        self._stream = sys.stderr   ##!< stream to which all output is written
        self._ready = True          ##!< @internal Flag to check initialization of singelton
```

For some reason doxygen tells me that `self._stream` (`Member _stream`) is undocumented. can I document it with a comment, like the doxygen docu describes in [Putting documentation after members](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#memberdoc) and if so, whats the right way?

**edit:**this seems to be related to me having no new line, for example here:

```
class escapeMode(object):
    '''
    Enum to represent the escape mode.
    '''
    ALWAYS      = 1     ##!< Escape all values
    NECESSARY   = 2     ##!< Escape only values containing seperators or starting with quotation
```

Doxygen only complains about `ALWAYS` being undocumented, I would like to avoid inserting newlines behind every new attribute I document this way since it destroys the value of newlines for separating logical blocks like loops or if statements from surrounding code

Comment: I would suggest to use [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for documentation of Python projects in general

Comment: unfortunately that is currently not an option, i will give it a look for the next project

Comment: maybe it was a spell-check tool that complained about `ALLWAYS` ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is currently not supported in doxygen, as previously answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6242634/1307974).
If you put the comment on the preceeding line it will work fine:

```py
class escapeMode(object):
    '''
    Enum to represent the escape mode.
    '''
    ## Escape all values
    ALLWAYS     = 1
    ## Escape only values containing seperators or starting with quotation
    NECESSARY   = 2
```

Hope that's not too late...

Comment: thanks, this is somewhat helpfull. I hacked a little bit on a filter for python. It does the same thing but it screws up line numbering since it internally converts it to your format but with docstrings, thus adding lines. I will change it and try to upload it somewhere if my employer allows.